# Создать div`ы из массива/цикл

Tags: html, jquery

```
  var bets = [{id: 1, value: 250},
               {id: 2, value: 200},
               {id: 3, value: 100}];
            for(var key in bets) {
                  var b = bets[key];
            }
```

И есть вот такой вот html код:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
       Айди вещи: 
      <span id="item_id">СЮДА Надо подставить "id" из массива</span>
       <br>
       Стоимость вещи: 
       <span id="value">СЮДА Надо подставить "value" из массива</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cоответственно в данном случае div с селектором `class="item"`, должно быть 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти div'ы должны быть в каком-то родительском элементе. Допустим, это будет div с классом container. Тогда

```
var bets = [
  {id: 1, value: 250},
  {id: 2, value: 200},
  {id: 3, value: 100}
],
content = '';

// "собираем" контент в цикле, подставляя нужные данные в шаблон 
bets.forEach(function (bet) {
  content += `
    <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
       Айди вещи: 
      <span id="item_id">${bet.id}</span>
       <br>
       Стоимость вещи: 
       <span id="value">${bet.value}</span>
    </div>
</div>
  `;
})
// добавляем собранный контент в существующий элемент для отображения его в браузере
// если используется jquery
$('div.container').append(content);
// если без jquery
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);
```

Comment: У меня чуть чуть изменилась структура bets https://jsfiddle.net/9u13vg2x/ там появилось значение items, в котором еще несколько значений. Как мне например вывести items => price?

Comment: Сначала нужно окончательно определиться со структурой данных, а потом уже вопрос задавать :) Определись со структурой и возвращайся к нам.

Comment: Ну, по идее вопрос такой же, только структура данных иначе. Создавать новый вопрос чтоли?)

Comment: нет, у тебя бред какой-то в фиддле написан. Определись сначала с фигурными и квадратными скобочками, что у тебя объект, а что массив и что друг в друге находится, а потом уже можно будет и в документ данные вставлять.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663172/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0