# Создать div`ы из массива

Tags: html, jquery

По идее вопрос идентичен этому: [Создать div`ы из массива/цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663160/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB/)

Только там я немного напутал структуру.

Есть массив

```
var bets = {name: "Геннадий" value: 100, items: [
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100}]},
           {name: "Геннадий" value: 100, items: [
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
              {name: "skin_name", price: 100}]};
            for(var key in bets) {
                  var b = bets[key];
            }
```

И есть вот такой вот html код:

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="item">
      Имя: 
      <span id="item_id">СЮДА Надо подставить "name" из массива</span>
      <br>
      Стоимость: 
      <span id="value">СЮДА Надо подставить "value" из массива</span>
      Вещи:
      <ul>
         <li>
            Название вещи: *СЮДА подставить значение из items (item_name)*<br>
            Стоимость вещи: *Сюда подставить значение из items (price)*
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Cоответственно в данном случае div с селектором class="item", должно быть 2 и в каждом блоке еще по 3 элемента в списке (items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bets = {
  name: "Геннадий",
  value: 100,
  items: [
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100}]
},{
  name: "Геннадий",
  value: 100,
  items: [
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100},
    {name: "skin_name", price: 100}
]},
content = '';

// "собираем" контент в цикле, подставляя нужные данные в шаблон 
bets.forEach(function (bet) {
  content += `
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      Имя: 
      <span id="item_id">${bet.name}</span>
      <br>
      Стоимость: 
      <span id="value">${bet.value}</span>
      Вещи:
      <ul>`;
      bet.items.forEach(function (item) {
        content += `
        <li>
          Название вещи: ${item.name}<br>
          Стоимость вещи: ${item.price}
        </li>`;
      });
      content += `
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>`;
});
// добавляем собранный контент в существующий элемент для отображения его в браузере
// если используется jquery
$('div.container').append(content);
// если без jquery
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);
```